# Using (?<=^) conditionally in ICU regex

Tags: regex

I have lines of text each on starting with either a digit, a vulgar fraction or just characters.

I am working with the ICU variant of Regex. I want to use `(?<=^)` to select white space at the beginning of all lines not beginning with digits of vulgar fractions.

I've tried: `(?<=^\s*)(?=\S)(?!\d+\/\d)` which selects the desired whitespace but for all lines without regard for any condition.

What am I missing?

**I've tried:**

```
^[a-zA-Z](?<=^)\s*

(?<=\R\s*)[a-zA-Z]\s*\D\s*

\s+(?=\n(?!(?:\d+  )?\d+\/\d))

^[a-zA-Z](?<=^)\s*
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
^\s+(?!\s)(?!\d+/\d+)
```

It matches spaces in beginning of line, that are not followed by `digits/digits`.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/mVZ3JJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "select white space at the beginning of all lines" then this pattern does `(?<=^\s*)(?=\S)(?!\d+\/\d)` not match anything as you are only using assertions which will hold a *position*

About the other patterns:

- `^[a-zA-Z](?<=^)\s*` Does not match anything as this assertion `(?<=^)` can never be true because it should have already matched `^[a-zA-Z]`
- `(?<=\R\s*)[a-zA-Z]\s*\D\s*` requires a newline to be present and the match starts with `[a-zA-Z]` which does not match spaces
- `\s+(?=\n(?!(?:\d+  )?\d+\/\d))` Will match 1+ whitspace chars only when followed by a newline and does not take "starting with either a digit, a vulgar fraction or just characters" into account

---

You might use:

```
^\h+\b(?!\d+\/\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitspace characters
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?!\d+\/\d)` Negative lookahead, assert not 1+ digits `/` and a digit directly to the right of the current position

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PREnFS/1)

Or if there should be only chars a-z or a digit to the right:

```
^\h+\b(?=[a-zA-Z\d])(?!\d+\/\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dv8NwV/1)